# Mixing ViewPager and Scrolling activity

Tags: android

I'm making application which mix ViewPager with Navigation bar and Scrolling activity. I won't provide you with code because, I use only merged Android Studio templates code for both.

[image]

This is how application looks like.

When it comes to scrolling, problem arise.

It doesn't reach the end of page, because title bar is visible.

[image]

And in order to scroll to bottom of page you need to move your finger to top of screen and scroll title in order to hide it.

[image]

I found out several tricky solution for this problem:

1. Make space at end of page.
2. Make title constant

But these solution doesn't appeal to me.

I need that scrolling works in following steps.

1. When you start scrolling, title is moving up and disappearing.
2. Then, fragment is scrolling until end of the page.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a CoordinatorLayout and put on the toolbar :

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

And put behaviour in your view pager :

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

The complete xml is something like this :

1. in your activiy xml :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout        
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"    
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

   <include layout="@layout/content_main"   
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView  
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
     app:menu="@menu/menu_main_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   ```
2. in your included xml, for example content_main.xml :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/vp_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

Comment: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" and
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"  are already implemented and it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Do you have enough item to be scrolled? It will not hide unless the item is more than height of the ViewPager

Comment: What layout_scrollFlags need to be for CollapsingToolbarLayout and what for Toolbar

Comment: Ahh.. sory i'm using Toolbar for creating my own toolbar with some images.. I think CollapsingToolbarLayout is good too..